# How do you create a deferred field with a SerializerMethodField?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to create a deferred method field in a model serializer using drf-flexfields.

I am using Django Rest Framework and drf-flexfields. I want to create a method field in my model serializer to make a complex query. Because retrieving this field will incur extra database lookups, I want this to be a deferred field, i.e. it will only be retrieved if the client specifically asks for it.

The DRF-Flexfields documentation seems to infer that a field can be deferred by only listing it in "expanded_fields" and not in the normal "fields" list, but gives no further explanation or example. https://github.com/rsinger86/drf-flex-fields#deferred-fields

I have tried creating a simple SerializerMethodField to test this:

```
class Phase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    assigned = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      blank=True,
                                      related_name="phases_assigned")


class PhaseSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    assignable_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_assignable_users")

    expandable_fields = {
        'assignable_users': (UserSerializer, {'source': 'assignable_users', 'many': True}),
    }

    class Meta:
        model = Phase
        fields = ['name', 'assigned']

    def get_assignable_users(self, phase):
        return {'test': 'this is a deferred field. It should only shows up when /?expand=assigned_users is given in '
                        'the api get request url'}
```

I get the following error :

"The field 'assignable_users' was declared on serializer PhaseSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option."

the desired result would be that a call to the api at /phase/ will return just the default fields specified in the meta "fields" list. "assignable_users" will only get returned if the client specifically asks for it with /phase/?expand=assignable_users.

What is the correct way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: try fields = ['name', 'assigned' , 'assignable_users']

Comment: Adding 'assignable_users' to the fields would cause it to be returned by default. I don't want 'assignable_users' to be returned by default in an api call to /phase/. I want it to be a "deferred" field. It only gets returned if the client requests /phase/?expand=assignable_users

Answer (score 0):

No matter it is a `SerializerMethodField`, you should add your `assignable_users` field in `Meta` fields:

```
class PhaseSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Phase
        fields = ['name', 'assigned', 'assignable_users']
        # _____________________________^
```

Check [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for more information.

Comment: I don't want 'assignable_users' to be returned by default in an api call to /phase/.
I want it to be a "deferred" field. It only gets returned if the client requests /phase/?expand=assignable_users

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a field in the serializer, you must include it in the fields option, as the error says. But if you do that, the field will be shown by default.

So, if you want a deferred field (on demand field), you can declare it in the model as a property:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   my_field1 = ...
   my_field2 = ...
   my_field3 = ...
   ...
   
   @property
   def deferred_field(self):
        return 'extra database lookups'
```

Then, in your serializer, you include it in expandable_fields as serializers.StringRelatedField:

```
class MySerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_field1', 'my_field2']
        expandable_fields = {
            'my_field3': (serializers.StringRelatedField),
            'deferred_field': (serializers.StringRelatedField),
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class PhaseSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    ...

    expandable_fields = {
       'assignable_users': (serializers.SerializerMethodField, {'read_only': True}),
       'assignable_users_m2m': (UserSerializer, {'source': 'assigned', 'many': True}),
    }
    class Meta:
       model = Phase
       fields = ['name', 'assigned']

    def get_assignable_users(self, phase):
        return {'test': '1111'}
```

Comment: Juts code wont help explain your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer